# Not able to execute GitLab runner job only if ref or variable conditions

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want that the CI only execute this job if I am on *master*, *merge reques*t, *scheduled pipeline* **OR** if the variable `COVERAGE_TEST` is equal to `ON`:

```yaml
c++TestCoverage:
  stage: analysis
  script: "./ciScripts/testCoverageScript.sh"
  tags:
    - framework
  dependencies:
    - c++Build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/test_coverage/
    expire_in: 1 week
    when: on_success
```

---

I tried adding the next lines:

```yaml
only:
  refs:
    - master
    - merge_requests
    - schedule
  variables:
    - $COVERAGE_TEST == "ON"
```

But the result is actully -> *If ((Master || MergeRequest || ScheduledPipeline) && COVERAGE_TEST == ON)*

---

I also tried with:

```yaml
only:
  variables:
    - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
    - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule'
    - $COVERAGE_TEST == "TRUE"
```

but `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'` does not work as I want because If I have the branch in merge request and I push some changes the value of `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `push`

---

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `rules` and `if` [keywords](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) to test all variables values and put OR between the tests.

Correct configuration in your case should be :

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" || $COVERAGE_TEST == "TRUE"'
      when: always
```

Comment: Yes, but that would do the same as what I put in the last option I tried. My problem with that one is that `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` is not true every time I push in branch that is in a merge request. Do you know any variable that does exactly that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the problem. `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is set to `"merge_request_event"` only when a merge request is opened.

Comment: Yes, what I would like is variable that tells me every time a push I donde to a branch that is in a merge request. In the case I put in the question ‘only: refs: merge_request’ does exactly that